# bootstrap theme: has-error is not working with password field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootswatch

I have the following code:

```
<div id="example1" class="has-error">
 <section>
   <label class="input">    
      <%= f.label :email %>     
      <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Enter Email"%>    
  </label>
 </section>
</div>
<div id="example" class="has-error">
 <section>
  <label class="input">    
      <%= f.label :password %> 
      <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Enter password" %>    
  </label>
 </section>
</div>
```

1. I have downloaded a theme from wrap bootstrap and everything was working fine but when I ran the above code I was not able to see the changes for password field that I should be getting by using "class="has-error".
2. It works fine for "text" type but it is not working with the password field. I guess this has something to do with my theme that I am using. I am not sure, I am saying so because when I was working without the theme the above code worked fine for both types that is for "text" as well as for "password".
3. I am not able to catch what could be my error, actually I am not able to figure out where could be the error. But people here always help and so I am posting my query here. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest providing link to the theme as well as creating jsfiddle at jsfiddle.com using that theme....

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the order of your CSS files if you don't want your theme to override bootstrap.

Hope this helps!